# How to 'tell database "My Database"' using Scripting Bridge?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, scripting-bridge, database-events

Following Rob Napier's [Scripting Bridge tutorial](http://robnapier.net/blog/scripting-bridge-265), I was able to set up the generated header for the [Database Events app](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/as_related_apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001570-SW1), `/System/Library/CoreServices/Database Events.app`. I am now trying to use Scripting Bridge to perform the equivalent of `tell database "My Database"`.

The corresponding AppleScript that I am trying to run via Scripting Bridge is:

```
tell application "Database Events"
    tell database "My Database"
        -- ...
    end tell
end tell
```

But how do I do this in Scripting Bridge?

The generated header contains:

```
// An application's top level scripting object.
@interface DatabaseEventsApplication : SBApplication
+ (DatabaseEventsApplication *) application;

- (SBElementArray *) documents;
- (SBElementArray *) windows;

@property (readonly) BOOL frontmost;  // Is this the frontmost (active) application?
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *name;  // The name of the application.
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *version;  // The version of the application.

- (DatabaseEventsDocument *) open:(NSURL *)x;  // Open an object.
- (void) print:(NSURL *)x printDialog:(BOOL)printDialog withProperties:(DatabaseEventsPrintSettings *)withProperties;  // Print an object.
- (void) quitSaving:(DatabaseEventsSavo)saving;  // Quit an application.

@end

//...

@interface DatabaseEventsDocument : DatabaseEventsItem

@property (readonly) BOOL modified;  // Has the document been modified since the last save?
@property (copy) NSString *name;  // The document's name.
@property (copy) NSString *path;  // The document's path.


@end

//...

@interface DatabaseEventsDatabase : DatabaseEventsItem

- (SBElementArray *) records;

@property (copy, readonly) NSURL *location;  // the folder that contains the database
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *name;  // the name of the database


@end

//...

@interface DatabaseEventsApplication (DatabaseEventsSuite)

- (SBElementArray *) databases;

@property NSInteger quitDelay;  // the time in seconds the application will idle before quitting; if set to zero, idle time will not cause the application to quit

@end
```

Do I need to use the `open:` method? Search through `databases`? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the [`objectWithName:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SBElementArray_Class/SBElementArray/SBElementArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005076-CH3-SW1) of `SBElementArray` worked:

```
DatabaseEventsApplication *dbevApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.databaseevents"];
DatabaseEventsDatabase *db = [[dbevApp databases] objectWithName:@"My Database"];
```

**UPDATE:** This was for a small project that I have posted to GitHub:  https://github.com/dtrebbien/Songs-Database-Viewer